# Can't connect to MySQL services after changing socket directory in my.cnf file

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I have changed the location of the socket file in my.cnf, however, when I try to login to mysql, I get the error "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 'prev/sock'" (I am using Prev/sock to denote that it is still looking for the previous location/default location).

I have added this parameter in my.cnf file

socket=/opt/data/sockpid/mysql.sock

I am using [mysqld] in my.cnf, not [client]

when I try using the command:

mysql -u root -p -S /opt/data/sockpid/mysql.sock - this bit is working

The parameter is not being read or not working correctly...

Answer (score 0):

If you change the location of the socket file in the `[mysqld]` section, you must also change it in the `[client]` section, or else clients will default to the original location.

As you said, you can specify a socket path when using the client, and that takes precedence over the configuration file or the default.

Comment: I don't have a client section...

Comment: Use a text editor and add one.